# Magento2: Login validation

Tags: magento-2.1, login, validation

In my login page. In button I want remove type attribute,

```
<button type="submit" class="action login primary" name="send" id="send2">
```

button type="submit" and want add onclick="custommethod()".

And in That custommethod() javascript function I want call existing Validation of magento2.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Follow Below Code

click event instead of onclick

```
<button type="submit" class="action login primary validation" name="send" id="send2">

<script>
require(["jquery"], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.validation').click(function () { // The button type should be "button" and not submit
           alert('validation');
        });
    });
});
        </script>
```